# Maximum number of user in Quickblox framework for Video and audio chat

Tags: android, ios, quickblox

I want to integrate group Video and Audio chat functionality with Quickblox framework  but have following doubt:

- Maximum number of user in one group chat .
- Can we perform multiple video chat on same time .
- Bandwidth information .

Note: Please also suggest if you have any better framework option to integrate cross platform video chat (iOS/Android) .

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maximum number of users in a call for **QuickbloxWebRTC** iOS SDK depends on hardware abilities.

**Video call**

For example, iPhone 6s+ can handle up to 7-10 users.

For iPhone 4s maximum number of users in multi call is 2-4, because iPhone 4s is lack of CPU performance.

**Audio call**

Even with 4s you can have up to 5-10 users at the same time.

6s can handle much more.

But the great advantage of **QuickbloxWebRTC** is that you can configure quality and cpu load http://quickblox.com/developers/Sample-webrtc-ios#Manage_local_video_track

If you prefer quality, set Full resolution for peer to peer calls.

If you prefer quantity, set Low resolution for peer to peer multi calls.

Everything depends on hardware you use, QuickbloxWebRTC doesn't have limits.

Comment: does Quickblox allows to record videos in Ios sdk or Android sdk?

Comment: Can we perform group audio call with more than 50 users? the notification will go to all the users although the first 5 responding to that call will be connected. I want to know if it is possible. will it make the application slow? and will the quality of the call between those 5 people be compromised?